# Merge Scala Seq

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have following Seq as input:

```
Seq(Seq(1,2),Seq(2,3),Seq(3,4),Seq(7,8),Seq(8,9))
```

I would like to create another Seq from this like below:

```
Seq(Seq(1,4),Seq(7,9))
```

I thought to use sliding operation (take 2) and merge as set to remove duplicates but I am not sure how to achieve it using Seq as it is immutable. Can someone help me?

Comment: And which logical operation would get you from the input to the output? What is the connection between the two?

Comment: What would be the correct output for input `Seq(Seq(4,5),Seq(6,7))`? Or input `Seq(Seq(3,8),Seq(11,43))`?

Comment: input - Seq(Seq(4,5),Seq(6,7)) output - Seq(Seq(4,5),Seq(6,7)) (input, output should be same - just I want to merge 2 seq if last element of first is same as first element of second)

Comment: Is your input always structured like this? Sequence of Sequences with exactly two items in it?

Comment: @Abhay what is the output if you have input `Seq(Seq(1, 2), Seq(2, 3), Seq(3, 4), Seq(7, 8), Seq(8, 9), Seq(4, 9))`?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if I understand that correctly, but try below code:

```
val input = Seq(Seq(1, 2), Seq(2, 3), Seq(3, 4), Seq(7, 8), Seq(8, 9))

input.flatten.groupBy(x => x).mapValues(_.size).filter{
  case (key, value) => value == 1
}.keySet.toList.sorted.grouped(2).toList
```

Output for such is:

```
input: Seq[Seq[Int]] = List(List(1, 2), List(2, 3), List(3, 4), List(7, 8), List(8, 9))

res0: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 4), List(7, 9))
```

Comment: You could use .collect instead of mapValues, filter and keySet: `input.flatten.groupBy(x => x).collect {
  case (key, value) if value.size == 1 => key
}.toList.sorted.grouped(2).toList`

Comment: Mind that this is completely predicated on `input.flatten` being sorted in ascending order. Although I guess you can assume anything you want, given the little amount of information in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to remove all consecutive duplicate values, so that if you have `Seq(..., (a, b), (b, c), ...)` it returns `Seq(..., (a, c), ...)`

If you always have two elements in your inside `Seq`s, you should rather use pairs than `Seq` (because as much information known at compile time as possible should be given in the types), so I'll do it with pairs, and hopefully, you'll be able to adapt if needed.

```
def merge(l: Seq[(Int, Int)], acc: Seq[(Int, Int)] = Seq()): Seq[(Int, Int)] = l match {
  //if there's less than one element left, nothing can be merged
  case Seq() | Seq(_) => acc ++ l
  //if the first two elements are mergeable, merge them and call recursively (to allow merging the new pair with the next element)  
  case (a, b) +: (c, d) +: tail if b == c => merge((a, d) +: tail, acc)
  //if the first two elements are not mergeable, put the first one in the accumulator, and carry on
  case p +: tail => merge(tail, acc :+ p)
}
```

You can probably replace this tail-recursive function by a `foldLeft`, but I find it more readable this way.

Answer (score 0):

A more generic `Seq`-based solution could be:

```scala
val data = Seq(Seq(1,2),Seq(2,3),Seq(3,4),Seq(7,8),Seq(8,9))
```

```scala
val merged = data.foldLeft(Seq.empty[Seq[Int]]) {
  case (acc :+ (last :+ tail), head :: e)
    if tail == head => acc :+ (last ++ e)
  case (acc, e) => acc :+ e
} //List(List(1, 4), List(7, 9))
```